# Laravel : logs out after ajax post request

Tags: session, laravel-5, session-state

Seems there is a bug with Laravel. recently i changed my session driver from file to database and noticed each time an Ajax post request is send then i get logged out .
[here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2314) is an issue somehow similar to mine.
if *remember me* is checked then i don't logged out but  i should refresh page for the next Ajax request to work,otherwise a *token mismatch exception* throw.
None of these issues is seen while using file session driver, but for some reason i need database driver.

Answer (score 0):

it was due to duplicate `web` middleware for api (ajax request) route.so the solution was in route file!